# Adding a basemap to a plot in Geopandas using X,Y coords

Tags: geopandas, contextily

I am having trouble adding a basemap to my map. My geodataframe is created using X and Y coords of a bunch of points.

```
gdf = geo.GeoDataFrame(
df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df['X'], df['Y']))

gdf.set_crs(epsg=3857)
```

Which look like this:
[image]

After using contexily to get a basemap, I cannot get the basemap to properly show up. The coords should be showing the bottom of the Mississippi River Basin.

```
ax = gdf.plot(color="red", figsize=(9, 9))
cx.add_basemap(ax, zoom=0, crs= gdf.crs)
```

[image]

Let me know if there is anything wrong with my code as to why it is not showing up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data is in WGS84/EPSG:4326 (i.e. lat/lon) coordinates. So I think you're confusing [`geopandas.GeoDataFrame.set_crs`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.set_crs.html), which tells geopandas what the CRS of the data is, with [`geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs.html), which transforms the data from the current CRS to the new one you specify. Also note that neither of these operations are in-place by default. So I think you want:

```py
gdf = geo.GeoDataFrame(
    df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df['X'], df['Y'])
)

gdf = gdf.set_crs("epsg:4326")

gdf_mercator = gdf.to_crs("epsg:3857")
```

Answer (score 0):

This really is same as @Michael Delgado answer.  It's simpler to state the CRS at **GeoDataFrame** construction time. Also make sure you are using correct CRS

### MWE

```
import geopandas as gpd
import geopandas as geo
import pandas as pd
import contextily as cx

# construct a dataframe with X and Y of some points in US
places = gpd.read_file(
    gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_cities"),
    mask=gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres")).loc[
        lambda d: d["iso_a3"].eq("USA")
    ],
)
df = pd.DataFrame({"X": places.geometry.x, "Y": places.geometry.y})

# user code, state CRS at construction time
gdf = geo.GeoDataFrame(
    df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df["X"], df["Y"]), crs="epsg:4326"
)
ax = gdf.plot(color="red", figsize=(9, 9))
cx.add_basemap(ax, zoom=0, crs=gdf.crs)
```

Comment: What's the difference betw `gpd` and `geo`?

Comment: no difference only imported as **geo** as original question code was calling it this... so just multiple names in namespace referring to same module